# UICollectionView inside TableView not populating cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a tableView with rows that need to be horizontally flowing collectionViews.

My tableView cells have a single collectionView within them, and then I instantiate them like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "CollectionCell", bundle: nil)
    cell.collectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

I'm trying to use an auto-height table view row, and I think this is what could be causing issues. How do I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension with internal collection views?

Comment: You may probably need to call `reloadData` after you have set the delegate and datasource

Comment: @Qazi did that in cellForRowAtIndexPath, no effect.

Comment: sorry I was not clear, so you are calling the `reloadData` on collection view right and not on the TableView?

Comment: @Qazi Yup. On the collection view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is in objective-c, but works for me:

i.  In your custom cell's .m file register the `UICollectionViewCell` nib, and specify you layout details (size, spacing etc.).

ii. in the VC that holds the tableView its .m do the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewCellId" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.collectionView.delegate = self;
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self;
    cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.collectionView reloadData];
```

iii. You can use the tag of the `UICollectionView` in the delegate methods to populate the right information

Hop this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to use an auto-height table view row, and I think this is what could be causing issues. How do I use UITableViewAutomaticDimension with internal collection views?

Comment: This does work. You need to make sure that the itemSize in the layout is set, and the autolayout constraints of the cell containing the collection view specify a height when the tableview is set to AutomaticDimension

Comment: @StefanKendall you are absolutely right, sorry forgot to include that..just added the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try adding - cell.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) - see below

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: MyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    let nibName = UINib(nibName: "CollectionCell", bundle: nil)
    cell.collectionView.registerNib(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
    cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
    cell.collectionView.delegate = self
    cell.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    return cell
}
```

See https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells for some more information.